# How can I import CSV files with '' and ' ' to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

Got a problem while importing CSV into a SQL Server database.

I have `, ,` and `,,` values in the CSV, so when I compare the values in SQL
`b.test = a.test` (i.e. `'' = ' '`) is false. So the insert is done, but test has an unique constraint and I get a constraint validation when `b.test = ''` and `a.test = ' '`.

How can I solve this problem?

Here the statement (b.marke = a.marke is the problem):

```
 INSERT INTO wt_umcodierung_bez(prnummer, marke, spk, bez, quelle) 
 SELECT a.prnummer, a.marke, a.spk, a.bez, a.quelle
 FROM trans_wt_umcodierung_bez a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM wt_umcodierung_bez b 
                  WHERE b.prnummer = a.prnummer
                    AND b.marke = a.marke
                    AND b.spk = a.spk)
 AND a.spk IN (SELECT spk FROM wt_spk)
```

Comment: what is the datatype of `test` column ? `'' =' '`  is true actually not false `select 1 where ' '= ''` will result `1`

Comment: *How* do you import the file? This should be handled by the cod that loads the data, it's not releated to SQL Server

Comment: It is varchar. It is part of a where clause. Will update the question.

Comment: @Sardoan I'll repeat the exact same question. Where is the code that imports the file? *That* code should understand CSVs, empty columns etc. Did you use bcp? SSIS, Code in C# ? Did you specify a text qualifier?

Comment: Not the SQL statement. That's just an insert from one table to another. Post the *code* that imports the CSV file. It's 1000 times harder to clean up dirty data than it is to properly import it

Comment: Since the SQL says '' = ' ' is false, but the uniquie constraint says it is true I would like to handle it in SQL. I think in Oracle this case woulb be no problem.

Comment: And *Please* don't mangle the database name. It's SQL Server. There is no such thing as "MS SQL-Database"

Comment: Oracle would also reject *text* values that aren't the same. You haven't posted *anything* related to CSVs, just a query that compares text fields. How did you import the data in those text fields?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server

Comment: Are you confused by Oracle's mapping of CSV files perhaps? That's not importing at all. Oracle can map a CSV file and treat it as a table. SQL Server doesn't have this feature. If you entered an entire line into `marke`, that's just a text value.

Comment: I import the data via c#. I dont want to change the code. Just want to change the SQL.

Comment: @Sardoan yes. I know. I was a SQL Server MVP. And talking about "MS SQL" is like screaming "I'm new". There's nothing wrong with the SQL statement. It's the C# code that enters dirty data to the table

Comment: I am MSCD Web Apps, Appbuilder and MCSA WebApps. At VW I also contact the MSSQL-Team if I have problems with a database. So in germany we call it this way.

Comment: Worst case, you'll have to split the strings into proper columns in SQL instead of C#. Just fix the C# code. Or use `bcp` or `SSIS` to import the data

Comment: OK. You win. Bad database.

Comment: I thought it could be something like comparing 'A' = 'a' -> true.

Comment: Can you use RTrim(b.marke) = RTrim(a.marke)?  If a space is stored in a.marke then the RTrim() will eliminate it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to double trim the fields in this case, to make sure you strip off any leading or trailing spaces. If you run into problems with NULL values, you can further wrap a.marke and b.marke in ISNULL, and then LTRIM(RTRIM())

```
INSERT INTO wt_umcodierung_bez(prnummer, marke, spk, bez, quelle) 
 SELECT a.prnummer, a.marke, a.spk, a.bez, a.quelle
 FROM trans_wt_umcodierung_bez a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM wt_umcodierung_bez b 
                  WHERE b.prnummer = a.prnummer
                    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(b.marke)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(a.marke))
                    AND b.spk = a.spk)
 AND a.spk IN (SELECT spk FROM wt_spk)
```

Comment: This query's performance will be *very* bad, because it won't be able to use any indexes on `marke`. Applying functions on a column prevents the query optimizer to use indexes, because the indexed values have nothing to do with the function results. This would force a full table scan of both tables.